# Given graph, find point $c$ at which $f$ has a jump discontinuity but is right-continuous. Find value of $f(c)$ to make $f$ left‑continuous at $c$.

Tags: calculus, limits, continuity, piecewise-continuity

**Question(s)**

> 1. Consider the graph of a function.
>    [image]
>
>    a. Find the point $c$ at which the function has a jump discontinuity but is right-continuous.
>
>    b. What value should be assigned to $f(c)$ to make $f$ left‑continuous at $x=c$?

> 2. Determine the point at which the function  $f(x)=(x−13)^{-1}$ is discontinuous. State the type of discontinuity from options
>
> - both left‑continuous and right‑continuous
> - neither left‑continuous nor right‑continuous
> - right‑continuous but not left‑continuous
> - left‑continuous but not right‑continuous
>
>    and whether the function is left‑ or right‑continuous.

**My Thought Process**

For `1a`, at first I entered $c=1$, but it says it was wrong because that was for "left continuous" so I think it is $c=5$ for right discontinuous. Is this correct?

I am kind of confused in `1b`, because is it asking for $f(5)$? If so, then I think the answer is $f(c) = 4$, but please correct and explain the right answer if I am wrong.

For `2`, Obviously this is an infinite discontinuity at $x=13$, but I'm not sure if infinite discontinuities can be left and right continuous. I think the answer is neither left and right continuous because when graphed, there is a vertical asymptote $x=13$. But is this correct?

Comment: There are three points of (two-sided) discontinuity for the values of $x$ shown: $x=1$ (left continuous, jump discontinuity, not right continuous), $x=3$ (neither left continuous nor right continuous; removable discontinuity), $x = 5$ (right continuous, jump discontinuity, not left continuous). You cannot re-define the function at $x=1$ to make it continuous at $x=1,$ and you cannot re-define the function at $x=5$ to make it continuous at $x=5.$ However, you can re-define the function at $x=3$ to make it continuous at $x=3$ (define $f(3) = 4.5,$ or whatever is the $y$-coordinate of the hole).